# Query xml data from SQL2000 (xml saved directly in a cell, multiple rows)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2000, openxml

Hi I get problem retrieve XML data from SQL2000 server.

The table structure is as following:

```
ID   Name   XML
1    Name1  <Root><DATA1>1-Data1</DATA2><DATA1>1-Data2</DATA2></Root>
2    Name2  <Root><DATA1>2-Data1</DATA2><DATA1>2-Data2</DATA2></Root>
3    Name3  <Root><DATA1>3-Data1</DATA2><DATA1>3-Data2</DATA2></Root>
```

How can I get the result out like this:

```
ID   Name   Data1   Data2
1    Name1  1-Data1 1-Data2
2    Name2  2-Data1 2-Data2
3    Name3  3-Data1 3-Data2
```

I am new SQL2000. Is such query possible in SQL2000?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005 and up, this would be no problem at all - if your XML very even valid, that is:

```
<Root> 
    <DATA1>1-Data1</DATA2>
    <DATA1>1-Data2</DATA2>
</Root>
```

You can't have an opening tag of `<DATA1>` and then a closing tag of `</DATA2>` - this is not well-formed XML and no XML parsing engine will be able to handle it....

But SQL Server **2000** doesn't really support XML processing (it can import XML and spit out XML, but it can't really process it) - I'm afraid you're out of luck with the 2000 version.